# How to convert ISO 8601 datetime in string list to utc datetime in python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

My code

[image]

Ouput:

[image]

Result I need:

[image]

How to convert to result I need from input list?

Tks for all helps!

Comment: Isn't it [`datetime.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) and [`datetime.isoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat)?

Comment: I tried to use datetime.fromisoformat, it just valid in string but my input list is string list.

Comment: Oh, also, post code, not a images of code. We need to be able to copy/paste it.

Comment: Many tks @Ouroborus I find out solution.

Comment: `print` will convert arguments to strings. `datetime` will convert to an ISO string in this situation. Use `repr()` is you want to print the object instead.

Answer (score 0):

tks for all attentions!

I find out solution

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

def get(date):
    date = [parser.parse(i) for i in date]
    return date

get(['2022-01-20T00:00:00.000Z' , '2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z','2022-04-20T00:00:00.000Z'])
```